# How to get the road name in google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

i want to get ONLY the road name in google maps not exact address, using either the geocoder or the directions service.i tried this results[0].address_components[1].long_name but it returns several different names (not necesserily wrong) on the same road.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a reverse geocode lookup on the location. Google provide this: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding