# How to get road coordinates by road name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, bing-maps

I need to have a service to tell me if a specific coordinate it's inside a road, by giving the coordinates, the road name and the country. Until now my best answer was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158145/how-to-get-the-road-name-in-google-maps), but for what I want it's probably not enough (too much webservice calls to the Reverse Geocoding service).

What's the best approach? Is there a service/database with road coordinates (full road, not just a few points)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "the best approach" is Google-direction-service(DRIVING),
which responds route along roads.

Geocoder responds major road name at specified point,
but It's may harmfull to geocode too many(over 100?)points in short time(few seconds).